# Making "./file" run as "file"

Tags: unix

I have a file named `scanner`:

```
#!/bin/sh
python lexAnalyser.py $*
```

I want it to run as `$ scanner test.txt` instead of `$ ./scanner test.txt`.

Thanks for any help you can give. I am just starting to use Linux and am trying to get my boots on.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? `./` tells shell that the preceeding file is an executable script

Comment: `set PATH= .:$PATH` (maybe to much `csh`?)

Comment: @Arpit Well it just tells the shell to execute that program in the current directory.

Comment: Slight correction: in your `.bashrc`, put `export PATH=$PATH:.`

Comment: @Arpit: No, the `./` tells the shell that it's in the current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
$ ./scanner test.txt
$ PATH=$PATH:$PWD
$ scanner test.txt
```

but it's preferable to have `$HOME/bin` in your path and your scripts there.

Comment: +1 for both giving an actual answer, as well as mentioning `$HOME/bin`. (And if you don't want to move the script to there, you can always symlink it. I don't know why you'd want that, but it's an option.)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the file in one of the paths specified by `$PATH`, for example, you can copy it to `/usr/bin` and then the shell will automatically recognize it by name without typing its full path.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the directory that `scanner` is in to your path
2. Move the file `scanner` to a directory that's already in your path.
3. Alias `scanner` to the full path of where the file is.